# Functor preserves restriction and corestriction

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, functors, morphism

I am working with modules, but I guess this question is valid with any abelian category.

Let $R$ be a ring, and $F$ a functor. Let $A, M$ be $R$-modules and $f : A \longrightarrow M$ a morphism. Let $B$ be a submodule of $A$ and $N$ a submodule of $M$ which contains $im \, f$.

1. Does $F$ preserve the restriction to $B$? More precisely, let $f|_B : B \longrightarrow M$ be the restriction of $f$ to $B$ and $Ff|_{FB} : FB \longrightarrow FM$ the restriction of $Ff$ to $FB$. Is it true that $F(f|_B) = Ff|_{FB}$?
2. Does $F$ preserve the corestriction to $N$? More precisely, let $f|^N : A \longrightarrow N$ be the corestriction of $f$ to $N$ and $Ff|^{FN} : FB \longrightarrow FN$ the corestriction of $Ff$ to $FN$. Is it true that $F(f|^N) = Ff|^{FN}$?
3. If we add some conditions to $F$, like $F$ is covariant/contravariant, additive, left/right exact etc... does the answer to 1 or 2 change?

Comment: Restriction is just composition with inclusion.

Comment: Yes, but functors don't necessarily preserve inclusions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2593095/404944

Comment: If $F$ does not preserve inclusions, how do you restrict $Ff$ to $FB$?

Comment: That's right, I hadn't thought about that

Comment: Covariant and contravariant aren't "additional conditions" that you apply to a general notion of "functor". Your question presumes $F$ is covariant. In fact, I recommend largely eliminating the notion of "contravariant functor". A "contravariant functor" from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal D$ can be identified with a (covariant) functor from $\mathcal{C}^{op}\to\mathcal D$. There is no need for a separate notion of "contravariant functor", and in my opinion it just creates unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @Derek: I think that's a little strong. One thing that's nice about the phrase "a contravariant functor $C \to D$" is that it saves you from having to make a choice about whether to consider it as a functor $C^{op} \to D$ or as a functor $C \to D^{op}$, and I can imagine there being situations where you want to avoid having to make this choice explicitly.

Comment: For example, suppose you want to compose a contravariant functor $C \to D$ with another contravariant functor $D \to E$ to get a covariant functor $C \to E$. In order to interpret this entirely in terms of covariant functors you need to interpret the first functor as a functor $C \to D^{op}$ but the second as a functor $D^{op} \to E$... so it doesn't entirely suffice to just always put the $^{op}$ on the target.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't have to imagine the mistakes and confusion I've seen by not tracking variance or forgetting that some functor is contravariant. The price of having to arbitrarily decide which of $F$ and $F^{op}$ should be $\mathcal{C}^{op}\to\mathcal{D}$ and occasionally using $F^{op}$ when the other is required seems minuscule to me compared to that. In fact, I usually find it a valuable cross-check to add $op$s as needed to make the "types" match. In other cases, it's crucial. For $P:\mathbf{Set}^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$, $P^{op}\dashv P$ but $P\not\dashv P^{op}$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole deal with functors is that they respect composition, so the standard maneuver here is to rephrase all of these constructions in terms of composition.

1. As Randall says in the comments, restriction is just composition with the inclusion $i : B \to A$, so it is still true that $F(f) : F(A) \to F(M)$ can be composed with the map $F(i) : F(B) \to F(A)$ (not necessarily an inclusion unless $F$ preserves monomorphisms, e.g. if $F$ is additive and left exact) to get $F(f \circ i) : F(B) \to F(M)$. This agrees with the restriction of $F(f)$ to $F(B)$ if $F(i)$ is a monomorphism but not in general.
2. "Corestriction" (I have never heard this name for the thing you're describing) involves lifting $f : A \to M$ to a map $g : A \to N$ such that $j \circ g = f$ where $j : N \to M$ is the inclusion. This gives $F(j \circ g) = F(f) : F(A) \to F(M)$ is the composition of $F(j) : F(N) \to F(M)$ and $F(g) : F(A) \to F(N)$, so again everything is fine if $F(j)$ is a monomorphism but not in general.
3. As mentioned in 1, $F$ preserves monomorphisms if it is additive and left exact but not in general.

Comment: By the way, from context it's clear that you want the source of $F$ to be $R$-modules but you don't say this and you really should. You also don't specify the target of $F$: is it modules over some other ring, abelian groups, $\text{Set}$, anything at all, etc. and this affects the answer, e.g. if it's not a (pre)additive category then it doesn't make sense to ask for it to be additive and "left exact" becomes more ambiguous.